# How to convert this Values in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have values like

```
3'023
'464
2'652
21.6%
'64
```

I am using the following SQL code to change into shown below;

```
UPDATE table 
SET Adjusted_value_tst = REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(value)), '''', '.')
WHERE [Value] LIKE '%''%';
```

Results:

```
3.023
0.464
2.652
21.6%
0.64
```

This is correct for 3 decimal values. But, I am supposed to convert '64 to 0.064

Please help me how should I modify my query in order to convert values like 
3'023 to 3.023 and '64 to 0.064

Thanks
Bob

Comment: Front-end tasks should not be perform by SQL motors

Comment: @GonzaloLorieto they are updating the database, not formatting the returned data. I don't see how this is a front-end task. If it was for displaying purposes only, then I could understand.

Comment: Do you also need to convert things like `'4` to `0.004` ?

Comment: @GonzaloLorieto, I am updating my table doing the cleansing part

Comment: Boy, you got a real mess in there... Anyway, what should be the result for `'21.6%'` after transformation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is always exactly one `'` in the data you can locate it with `charindex()`. From there you can calculate the length of the portions left and right to the `'`. If the right length is less than 3, you can use `stuff()` and `replicate()` to insert as much `0`s as needed. If the left portion's length is less than 1, prepend a `0` (else nothing, i.e. an empty string). Then do your `replace()` as you already did. (Of course you can also do it the other way round, first replace an then do the aforementioned.)

```
UPDATE elbat
       SET adjusted_value_tst = replace(CASE
                                          WHEN charindex('''',
                                                         rtrim(ltrim(adjusted_value_tst))) < 2 THEN
                                                           '0'
                                                         ELSE
                                                           ''
                                                       END
                                                       +
                                                       stuff(rtrim(ltrim(adjusted_value_tst)),
                                                             charindex('''',
                                                                       rtrim(ltrim(adjusted_value_tst)))
                                                             + 1,
                                                             0,
                                                             replicate('0',
                                                                       3
                                                                       - len(rtrim(ltrim(adjusted_value_tst)))
                                                                       + charindex('''',
                                                                                   rtrim(ltrim(adjusted_value_tst))))),
                                                      '''',
                                                      '.');
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c31f5/27)

Comment: the query worked now I can able to see 0.064 instead 0.64. But I have one concern here, please help me fix this one. Instead of 21.6% the result now is 021.6% after updating. How to fix this ?

Comment: @Bob: I don't see such a value in your sample data. How does it look before transformation?

Comment: @Bob if you have more than 1 scenario in your data, include all the scenarios. What should 21.6% be? 0.216?

Comment: I have percentages values also included. My main concern is conversion of '64 to 0.064, but also I have values like 21.2%. Apologies for not stating in the question itself.

Comment: But now I have this 21.2% updated as 021.2%, can you please tell me how to fix this issue?

Comment: @Bob: Probably replacing the `%` with the empty string prior to any other transformation (mine or Larnu's, which might the cleverer way if you really only have number representations in there, BTW) is enough?

Comment: What should the value be? Update your question to show **every** scenario, with sample and expected results. The volunteers here can't give an answer if they don't know what values exists, or what the result should be.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the `'` and then divide by 1000:

```
SELECT *, REPLACE(N,'''','') / 1000.0
FROM (VALUES ('3''023'),('''464'),('2''652'),('''64')) V(N);
```

If you have to have it to 3 decimal places then use `CONVERT` to change the value to a `decimal(12,3)` or similar.

Edit:

It seems the OP doesn't know the syntax for an `UPDATE`. This would be:

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET YourColumn = REPLACE(YourColumn,'''','') / 1000.0;
```

Edit 2:

The OP has more scenarios than were initial described. This *should* (edit now it does) work, provided there aren't more scenarios we aren't aware of...:

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET YourColumn = ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(20),CONVERT(decimal(12,3),TRY_CONVERT(decimal(12,3),REPLACE(YourColumn,'''','')) / 1000)), YourColumn);
```

This involves several nested `CONVERT`s. It's not exactly "pretty", however, it is quite simple. The need for the outer `CONVERT` after the intial `TRY_CONVERT` is so that the value only has 3 decimal places. A `decimal(12/3) / decimal(4,0)` would result in a scale of `max(6, s1 + p2 + 1) = max(6, 3 + 4 + 1) = max(6,8) = 8`, which is more than the OP wants. *So the value `'3'023'` would have ended up as the value `'3.02300000'`.* [Precision, scale, and Length (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: I have 1 million rows in my table, can you please tell me how to do this dynamically in the Query itself? thanks

Comment: What do you mean dynamically? Why not just a simple `UPDATE` statement? There's no need for Dynamic SQL.

Comment: I have 1 million + rows, how can I do this for all the values?

Comment: @Bob I have added an this for you, however, I suggest looking into the `UPDATE` syntax if you are unfamiliar with it. It's one of basics of SQL, so it's something you'll want to learn sooner, rather than later.

Comment: As I am new to SQL I am learning new things everyday. Thank you for your information.

Comment: @Bob added another attempt based on your lastest info. This is a guess though still, as I'm concerned you have other scenarios we don't know about.

Comment: Also added a bit of information for you, which'll help your understanding @Bob .

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps, but you can build a conversion table of the unique (Distinct) values which need to be converted, then lookup the proper value in your Update statement.

I have exported data to Excel to get a better handle on my data, then run some formula with an output column. Imported it back into Sql and performed an update from the conversion.  But whatever you do before changing the data, back up the table.